# Processing array of data with promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I'm seeking guidance on how best to handle the following scenario. I'm fairly new to JS and async development, so I'm trying to understand the best way to handle this. I call one api (callAPI) which returns an array of items. I need to take those items and send them to another api (callAPI2) but that api doesn't have a bulk method, so I have to call the api for each item in the array. Below is how I have it structured: getArray promise returns the first array, I send the array to promise 2 (getIndividualData) where I loop and call the second api. I'm wondering if there are better ways to structure this? If I pass in a large array, I may need to pace the calls to the api so I don't get throttled... so maybe I need some version of Promise.all?

```
let getArray = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        callApi.get().on('success', function(result, response) {
            resolve(result);
        }); 
    });
}

let getIndividualData = function(arrayOfItems) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        var responseArray = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfItems.length; i++) {
            callApi2.get(arrayOfItems[i]).on('success', function(result, response) {
                responseArray.push(result);
            }); 
        }
        resolve(responseArray);
    });
}

let failureCallback = function() {
    return "Error!";
}

getArray().then(function(response) {
    return getIndividualData(response);
}).then(function(finalArray) {   
    console.log(`The final array is ${JSON.stringify(finalArray)}`);
}).catch(failureCallback);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a request for each item in a large array without getting throttled by implementing a concurrency throttler with a Set of Promises and async/await syntax. I've duplicated your code below, modifying the implementation of getIndividualData and passing in `concurrency` as an option.

```js
let getArray = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        callApi.get().on('success', function(result, response) {
            resolve(result);
        }); 
    });
}

let getIndividualData = async function(arrayOfItems, { concurrency }) {
  var promiseSet = new Set(),
      responseArray = [],
      i = 0;
  while (i < arrayOfItems.length) {
      if (promiseSet.size >= concurrency) {
          await Promise.race(promiseSet)
      }
      const promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
          callApi2.get(arrayOfItems[i]).on('success', function(result, response) {
              resolve(result)
          })
      })
      responseArray.push(promise.then(result => {
        promiseSet.delete(promise)
        return result
      }))
      i += 1

  }
  return Promise.all(responseArray)
}

let failureCallback = function() {
    return "Error!";
}


getArray().then(function(response) {
    return getIndividualData(response, { concurrency: 10 });
}).then(function(finalArray) {   
    console.log(`The final array is ${JSON.stringify(finalArray)}`);
}).catch(failureCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reformulating this to a helper that promisifies an object that has an `.on('success')` event handler and an async function for the top-level `.then()`ish code gives us something like this...

To pace the API calls, add in [`p-limit`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-limit) or similar to `getIndividualData`.

```
function promisifyOnSuccessObj(onSuccessObj) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    onSuccessObj.on("success", (result, response) => resolve(result));
    // TODO: what about `response`?
    // TODO: onSuccessObj.on('error')..?
  });
}

function getIndividualData(arrayOfItems) {
  // Returns an array of promises
  return arrayOfItems.map((item) =>
    promisifyOnSuccessObj(callApi2.get(item)),
  );
}

async function doThings() {
  const result = await promisifyOnSuccessObj(callApi.get());
  const individualDatas = await Promise.all(getIndividualData(result));
  console.log(`The final array is ${JSON.stringify(individualDatas)}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could combine `Promise.all`, `map` and `async...await` syntax and in the end get one array of resolved individual promises based on the previous resolved array promise.

```js
const mockApi = {
  request: (response) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(response), 1000)
    })
  },
  getArray() {
    return this.request(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
  },
  getItem(item) {
    return this.request(`Resolved: ${item}`)
  }
}


async function getData() {
  const array = await mockApi.getArray();
  const final = await Promise.all(array.map(e => mockApi.getItem(e)));
  console.log(final)
}

getData()
```